# Гистограмма matplotlib в виджете PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-designer, matplotlib

Не могу понять как вставлять различные графики в конкретный, созданный в моей форме виджет, который создан при помощи *QT Designer*.

Посмотрел кучу рекомендаций, но ни одна не удовлетворила, либо из-за того, что не полный код и логика работы программы мне не понятна, либо в следствии реализации отличающейся задачи. 
Помогите пожалуйста.

**forma2.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(620, 584)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow) #1
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")

        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.widget)

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("Графік")

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 620, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
```

**main.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from forma2 import Ui_MainWindow
from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtCore, QtWidgets
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import (
        FigureCanvas, NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)
# FigureCanvas - холст
# NavigationToolbar - панель управления
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()
   
   
class MyMplCanvas(FigureCanvas):   # Класс, представляющий собой холст для рисования
    def __init__(self,fig, parent = None):
        # Подаём на вход рисунок (экземпляр класса Figure)
        self.fig = fig
        # Вызов суперкласса (инициализация холста)
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self,self.fig)  #(self,self.fig)
        # Определяем характер поведения размеров холста как Expanding
        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        # Сообщаем системе, что политика геометрии для объекта изменилась
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)  # Это нужно для инициализации нашего дизайна
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.getFirst)


    def getFirst(self, fig):
        # graph = LoadGrafik()
        # self.fig = graph.printGraphFirst()
        self.fig = LoadGrafik()
         
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget)

        # получение объекта класса холста с нашим рисунком
        self.canavas = MyMplCanvas(self.fig)

        # Размещение экземпляра класса холста в шаблоне размещения

        self.widget.addWidget(self.canavas)

        # получение объекта класса панели управления холста

        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canavas, self)

        # Размещение экземпляра класса панели управления в шаблоне размещения
        self.widget.addWidget(self.toolbar)


    def LoadGrafik():
        labels = ['G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5']
        men_means = [20, 34, 30, 35, 27]
        women_means = [25, 32, 34, 20, 25]

        x = np.arange(len(labels))  # расположение столбиков
        width = 0.35  # толщина столбика
        # print(x)
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/2, men_means, width, label='Men')
        rects2 = ax.bar(x + width/2, women_means, width, label='Women')

        
        ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
        ax.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
        ax.set_xticks(x)
        ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
        ax.legend()

        ax.bar_label(rects1, padding=3)
        ax.bar_label(rects2, padding=3)

        fig.tight_layout()
        
        return fig  

   
   ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(Window.getFirst) 


sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

В результате получаю ошибку:

> TypeError: getFirst() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fig'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычно, вставка графиков выглядит так:

```
import random
import numpy as np

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(620, 584)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow) 
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.widget)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("Графік")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 620, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))


class MyMplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fig = Figure()
        super(MyMplCanvas, self).__init__(self.fig, *args, **kwargs)

    def plot(self, labels, men_means, women_means, x, width):          # !!!
        self.fig.clear()                                               # !!!
        
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)                            # !!!
        
        rects1 = self.ax.bar(x - width/2, men_means, width, label='Men')
        rects2 = self.ax.bar(x + width/2, women_means, width, label='Women')
        self.ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
        self.ax.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
        self.ax.set_xticks(x)
        self.ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
        self.ax.legend()

        self.draw()                                                    # !!!
        

class Sheet(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self._plot)

        self.canavas = MyMplCanvas()
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canavas, self)
        
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.canavas)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)

    def _plot(self):
        labels = ['G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5']
        men_means = [ random.randrange(1, 100) for _ in range(5) ]
        women_means = [ random.randrange(1, 100) for _ in range(5) ]
        x = np.arange(len(labels))          # расположение столбиков
        width = 0.35                        # толщина столбика        
        
        self.canavas.plot(labels, men_means, women_means, x, width)    # !!!


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Sheet()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

---

**Update**

> В коде разобрался, но хотелось чтобы `NavigationToolbar` графика появлялась не до нажатия кнопки, а после нажатия (вместе с гистограммой).

```
import random
import numpy as np

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(620, 584)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow) 
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.widget)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("Графік")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 620, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))


class MyMplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fig = Figure()
        super(MyMplCanvas, self).__init__(self.fig, *args, **kwargs)

    def plot(self, labels, men_means, women_means, x, width):          
        self.fig.clear()                                               
        
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)                            
        
        rects1 = self.ax.bar(x - width/2, men_means, width, label='Men')
        rects2 = self.ax.bar(x + width/2, women_means, width, label='Women')
        self.ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
        self.ax.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
        self.ax.set_xticks(x)
        self.ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
        self.ax.legend()

        self.draw()                                                    
        

class Sheet(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self._plot)

        self.canavas = MyMplCanvas()
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canavas, self)
        
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.canavas)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        self.toolbar.hide()                                            # +++

    def _plot(self):
        labels = ['G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5']
        men_means = [ random.randrange(1, 100) for _ in range(5) ]
        women_means = [ random.randrange(1, 100) for _ in range(5) ]
        x = np.arange(len(labels))          # расположение столбиков
        width = 0.35                        # толщина столбика        
        
        self.canavas.plot(labels, men_means, women_means, x, width)    
        self.toolbar.show()                                            # +++

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Sheet()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дружище спасибо тебе большое!!! Всё работает!! Так как мне надо!!

Comment: @AlexProkop, пожалуйста.   Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: В коде разобрался, но хотелось ба чтобы NavigationToolbar графика появлялась не до нажатия кнопки, а после нажатия (вместе с гистограммой).

Comment: @AlexProkop я добавил обновление в свой ответ, проверьте.

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо!!!
Всё работает замечательно!!! Обязательно учту Вашу помощь в своих дальнейших наработках!!!
Успехов Вам и творческого вдохновения!
Считаю, что благодаря Вам вопрос полностью закрыт.

Comment: По этому же вопросу возникла новая проблема....
При добавлении нового графика в классе MyMplCanvas , скажем, plot_2, который отличается построением от plot и набором параметров _plot_2 в классе  Sheet, при первом запуске (для него создана своя кнопка) график  plot_2 высвечивается на экране, но при переключении на plot и обратно на plot_2 на экране остаётся только график plot. 
Помогите разобраться, как апдейтить мой widget

Comment: @AlexProkop если у вас возникли другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос. Приложите пример, который демонстрирует проблему и расскажите что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.

Comment: Всё разобрался!!!
Хотел удалить комментарий, но Вы уже на него ответили!!
В следующий раз сделаю как Вы рекомендуете